# How to get dynamic activity label based on the matching intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have different Intent filters set on an Activity to handle different file pattern. Everything works fine, but what I would like is to be able to display different Activity name in the Android action chooser screen depending on the file pattern. For now, it just displays the activity label...
Is it possible to override the label per Intent filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `<intent-filter>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) supports an `android:label` attribute.

Comment: Thanks I just found out after posting. I was adding the label to the action tag before that...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the solution:

```
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    switch(filePattern) {
        case 0:
            ab.setTitle("My Title");
            break;
        ...
        default:
            ab.setTitle("Nothing");
    }
```